# CSS Body and Header Issue

Tags: html, css

I have used the following code for the body as its a responsive site

```
.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}
```

After body i have added a header with css as below

```
.topheader {
    height: 5%;
    background-color: #ff6d00;
    width:100%
}
```

The Problem what i am facing is i need the header 100% but its fixing to 70% because of the body width.

I need the body width 70% also i need the header width 100% inside body.

Is there any chance we can align it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works...

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ 
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 87.5%;
            font-family: arial;
            line-height: 1.5;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .body{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 70%;
            clear: both;
        } 
        .topheader{ 
            height: 5%;
            background-color:#ff6d00;
            width: 200%;    
            } 
        .laser{
            float:left;
            padding:40px;
            margin-top:-35px;
        }
    </style>

<body class="body">
    <div class="topheader" style="margin-left:-250px">
        <nav> 
            <ul style="margin-left:180px;">
                <li class="laser">Books</li>
                <li class="laser">Video</li>
                <li class="laser">Audio</li>
                <li class="laser">Download</li>
                <li class="laser">Login</li> 
                <li class="laser">Register</li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Shyam Kashyap  Try this.

Comment: I tried it, but here what is happeing is when i switch to a screen with 1350 screen resolution its breaking...

Comment: Ok, but this will also break when it goes to a different screen resolution may be 1600 or so?

Comment: For that case you have to learn about the media queries ,I will give you the link to make page responsive  of youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA1NW-T1QXc`  Here you will know how to make page responsive for different resolution

Answer (score 2):

You just Check this Demo.I think you want to like this.You never give the width to body.

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0 auto;background-color:#ccc;}
.header{float:left;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;padding:10px 0;background-color:#000;color:#fff;margin:0;}
.container{margin:0 auto;width:70%;background-color:#fff;height:200px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
This is an Demo

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes  that's right here container is a div but in my code its body this code did not work

Comment: Hi
You just Check the Snippet Code So you Can See the CSS Code.And if you are Satisfy with my Answer then Upvote me and Approved it.

Comment: this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you want that your header is about 100% of the viewport and the body only had 70% of the viewport?

I would say you have to set the css:

```
#viewport
{
 width:100%;
 [...]
}
.body
{
width:70%;
[...]
}
.header
{
width:100%;
[...]
}
```

When you have the body that is inherit from viewport that is 100% of the width, you can set the body to 70% and the header, that is inherit from viewport too, had about 100%.

Of course you can set the header outside from the body and give him 100%, so you don't need the extra #viewport.

Comment: This did not work the problem is that body we are setting to 70% but we need the background image in the header inside the body to be 100%

Comment: So you want the header set to 100% IN the body, so that he's almost 70% of the site (cause of body) or you want to set the header as 100% IN the viewport?

Comment: I need header on the body while body remains 70% but header background only needs to be 100% Please make sure the content inside the header should be 70% as it is only background needs to be 100%

Comment: Here is the code if necessary

body{ color: #000000; font-size: 87.5%; /* This is base font size 14px*/ font-family: arial; line-height: 1.5; text-align: left; } .body{ margin: 0 auto; width: 70%; clear: both; } .topheader{ height: 5%; background-color: #ff6d00; width: 100%; } <body class="body"> <div class="topheader"> <nav> <ul> <li>Books</li> <li>Video</li> <li>Audio</li> <li>Download</li> <li>Login</li> <li>Register</li> </ul> </nav> </div> </body>

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is becuase you have written **body** as a class.

```
.body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Instead of that you have to write only body, **remove the dot before body**.

```
body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}
```

If you are taking body as a class in that case write

First write the **body** class

```
.body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Then write **topheader** class like this

```
.body  .topheader
{
    height: 5%;
    background-color:#ff6d00;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: This did not work the problem is that body we are setting to 70% but we need the background image in the header inside the body to be 100%

Comment: @Shyam Kashyap as i answered above you have to write header class like i mentioned above

Comment: Clarify me , do you want your background image to be 100% inside the body(class) or the body

Comment: I need header on the body while body remains 70% but header background color or background image only needs to be 100%. Please make sure the content inside the header should be 70% as it is

Comment: body{
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 87.5%; /* This is base font size 14px*/
 font-family: arial;
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-align: left;

}

.body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 clear: both;

}

.topheader{
 height: 5%;
 background-color: #ff6d00;
 width: 100%;
}

<body class="body">

<div class="topheader">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>Books</li>
     <li>Video</li>
     <li>Audio</li>
     <li>Download</li>
     <li>Login</li>
     <li>Register</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
</div>

</body

Comment: So you want the list elements to displayed on to the header

Comment: yes but that would be fixed to 70% as usual as body but div with class topheader background color needs to be 100%, Only Color